# Why does my cross sites OPTIONS request on Firefox takes so much time?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, cookies, cors

I have encountered a strange behaviour on Firefox (51.0.1) that causes my request
to take 5 seconds to perform. This does not happens in Chrome or Safari.

**Some background first**

In the web application I work on, a user must login on a specific service
(let's say it is running on `foo.bar.com`). The authentication server responds
with a `SET-COOKIE` header for the domain `.bar.com` so that every subdomains of
`.bar.com` can use this auth token.

The javascript code that is performing the auth request looks like this:

```
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.withCredentials = true;
    request.open('POST', 'http://foo.bar.com/login');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    request.onload = (evt) => {
        doSomeStuff();
    }

    request.send(JSON.stringify({ username: 'foo', password: 'bar' });
```

```

**Actual bug**

Due to the cross-domain cookie, I have to set `request.withcredentials = true`,
this is where the (bug|feature) happens: The preflight OPTIONS request takes
5 seconds to achieve. The following POST request is executed normally.
The Firefox's inspector tells me that the requests is stuck in the `waiting` state
for about 5 seconds (between 4600ms and 5000ms in my tests). This takes the
same time on different machines. Moreover, this only happens when the request
is emitted when clicking on the "login" button (when I replay the same request
via the "Edit and resend functionnality in the inspector, the request is performed
in 18ms).

I didn't find anything about this on the MDN documentation
(which makes me think of a bug).

Does anyone now why the browser behaves like this ? Or if I am doing something
wrong ?

Comment: that all looks fine - perhaps your server is doing something different?

Comment: I don't think the latency comes from the server since it depends on which brower is used. Also queries sent via curl are normally processed.